Cursor-pointer class is not working in Vuetify 3
I am having trouble getting the class cursor-pointer to work in Vue3 with Vuetify, I tried using it according to the Vuetify documentation.
It is a big project in a company and everything basic is set up and working as it should. I have tried something simple such as <span class="cursor-pointer">Test</span>. The class shows up in the html element in inspect but it shows nothing down in the styles/computed area.
I tried with <span class="text-right"></span> just to see if Vuetify works in the component and it does work just fine.
If it helps, here is the entire component and I have tried to put the class on every level of the DOM but nothing works:
<template>
  <v-menu>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
      <span v-bind="props" class="cursor-pointer">
        <v-icon size="x-large">mdi-account-outline</v-icon>
        <span>{{ accountName }}</span>
      </span>
    </template>
  </v-menu>
</template>


We need enough code to reproduce the issue, see this sandbox of your code working fine in isolation. It indicates the issue is elsewhere in your app, maybe an overriding style.

Does it Work set cursor just with style or with a custom self made class?

@Christoph, yes it does work with my own class.

@yoduh, not sure what to give you, I gave you simple code of what I have.

then use custom self made gg

@Christoph, not really an answer to my question, I use vuetify and all other works but this one doesn't. I am asking why, of course I can make my own classes but not sure why I cant access some vuetify classes

i know but the class itself does not more as cursor: xxx, so if you have time to spend for debugging such a small thing then go ahead ;), sure there is some infos in chrome dev tools when you look into the css stuff either, I would tipp that a other thing override the cursor or so like  @yoduh has written because it works isolated in the sanbox
